# How to keep data sources synchronized with firebase realtime database with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase realtime database. Data structure is an array of posts, which user can also comment and like.

I retrieve data like this and put them into a local `posts` array:

```
ref.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) -> Void in
  self.posts.append(snapshot)
  self.tableView.reloadData()
})
```

They are displayed correctly and no problems so far. Now let's say user *likes* a post. I add his id to `likers` array of post in local `posts` array. However firebase database don't know this yet.

My question is what is the correct way to keep local data and firebase data synchronized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick with Firebase is usually to only update the database when the user performs an action, such as liking a post. From that database update you then get a new event, for example a `.childChanged` for updating the likes. You then update your UI based on the event from the database.

This is sometimes known as a reactive model, or more formally as [Command Query Responsibility Segregation](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html): you separate the flow of the commands (from user to database) from the flow of the queries (from database to views).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That makes sense, but drawback is that it is slower to update the views right?

Comment: Not really. Firebase's Database does a neat little trick here: it fires the local `.childChanged` before it sends the command to the server, so it's pretty much instant. It also handles edge cases, such as when the server rejects the write operation. But the important things are: 1) the user gets the behavior they expect (fast updates) 2) you don't have to write specific code to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

You should use DatabaseHandler. You should listen your database and then remove handler when you leave your viewcontroller.

```
fileprivate lazy var ref = Database.database().reference().child("...")
private var yourHandler: DatabaseHandle?

override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

   yourHandler = ref.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) -> in
      self.posts.append(snapshot)

      DispatchQueue.main.async {
         self.tableView.reloadData()
      }
   })  
 }

deinit {
   if let handler = yourHandler {
      ref.removeObserver(withHandle: handler)
   }
}
```

Now, when you add new item to database, your handler get this item and display it in your viewcontroller.
Note: Always call the reloadData () method on the main thread

Comment: I already can display posts. My question is how to modify them.